# Different output between compilers

Tags: c

I am doing the first problem on Project Euler.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    int sum;
    while (number < 1000) {
        if (number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
            sum += number;
            number++;
        }
        else {
            number++;
        }
    }
    printf("The answer is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this via compileonline.com, I get 233168. When I compile this in gcc I get 2686824. What causes this difference?

Comment: `number`, `sum` are not initialized, hence undefined behavior.

Comment: compiling with `gcc -Wall` would have indicated the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compileonline probably initializes the variables.

You have to initialize them manually.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (number < 1000) {
        if (number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
            sum += number;
            number++;
        }
        else {
            number++;
        }
    }
    printf("The answer is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```